# Ranking in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to give rank to records based on follows

Based on b_id and priority combination need to rank distinct combination in priority sequence and then again recursively.
Example:

[image]

Can someone help me with a T-SQL

Comment: Teradata and tsql? Are you using Teradata, MS SQL Server or Sybase?

Comment: "T-SQL" is NOT Teradata SQL.  It refers to the scripting language Transact-SQL, used by SQL Server and Sybase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a rank, you want a row_number:

```
SELECT ...,
   Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY acct_id ORDER BY rn, priority) AS rnk
FROM
 (
   SELECT ...,
      Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY acct_id, priority ORDER BY b_id) AS rn
   FROM mytab
 ) AS dt
```

Comment: Think maybe you left some stuff out of your derived table/inner query.

Comment: Better now? :-)